# Convert date type object to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, typeconverter

I have a dataframe with Date_Birth in the following format: July 1, 1991 (as type object).
How can I change the entire column to datetime?

Thanks

Comment: Please include a script that initializes the dataframe so that we can have complete, tested answers. It could be a single column with a few rows of strings in that format.

Comment: Check this Stack Overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function. You can write out a format specifier in the `strptime` format or have python guess the format. In your case, guessing works.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({"Date":["July 1, 1991"]})
>>> pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%B %d, %Y") 
0   1991-07-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], infer_datetime_format=True) 
0   1991-07-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```